# knitr pdflatex output discrepancy between console and PDF

Tags: pdf, knitr, rstudio, pdflatex

I am running RStudio Version 0.98.484 and R version 3.0.2 on OS X Mavericks.

While using knitr I noticed a discrepancy between the console output from a summary() command  and that generated in the PDF (via pdflatex). Here is the example.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{MinionPro}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}
\usepackage[margin = 1 in]{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=2.5cm,bmargin=2.5cm,lmargin=2.5cm,rmargin=2.5cm}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[unicode=true,pdfusetitle,
 bookmarks=true,bookmarksnumbered=true,bookmarksopen=true,bookmarksopenlevel=2,
 breaklinks=false,pdfborder={0 0 1},backref=false,colorlinks=false]
 {hyperref}
\hypersetup{
 pdfstartview={XYZ null null 1}}
\usepackage{breakurl}

\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\definecolor{darkred}{rgb}{0.5,0,0}
\definecolor{darkgreen}{rgb}{0,0.5,0}
\definecolor{darkblue}{rgb}{0,0,0.5}
\hypersetup{ colorlinks,
linkcolor=darkblue,
filecolor=darkgreen,
urlcolor=darkred,
citecolor=darkblue }

\definecolor{keywordcolor}{rgb}{0,0.6,0.6}
\definecolor{delimcolor}{rgb}{0.461,0.039,0.102}
\definecolor{Rcommentcolor}{rgb}{0.101,0.043,0.432}

\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{breaklines=true,showstringspaces=false}


\makeatletter
\newcommand\gobblepars{%
    \@ifnextchar\par%
        {\expandafter\gobblepars\@gobble}%
        {}}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\R}{R}

\title{\textsc{Laboratory Session 1}}
\author{Ani}



\begin{document}

<<setup, include=FALSE, cache=FALSE>>=
library(knitr)
# set global chunk options
opts_chunk$set(fig.path='figure/minimal-', fig.align='center', fig.show='hold')
options(replace.assign=FALSE, width=90, tidy=TRUE)
render_listings()
@

\maketitle
<<chunk26>>==
require(rpart) 
data(car90)
summary(car90$Price) 
@

Hello!


\end{document}
```

The console shows:

```
> summary(car90$Price)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max.    NA's 
   5866    9995   13070   15810   19940   41990       6
```

the pdf shows

```
Min. 1st Qu. Median Mean  3rd Qu. Max.  NA 's
5870 10000   13100  15800 19900   42000  6
```

Why would this be happening? There are no decimals to round up. Any clues would be much appreciated.

Thanks!!

Ani

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because `knitr` sets `options(digits=4)`, and the default value of the `digits` option is 7 in R. You can reproduce it by

```
library(rpart)
options(digits=4)
summary(car90$Price)
```

Comment: Thanks Yihui! As always you come to the rescue.